# Error code in the automatic door system

Tags: electrical-engineering, electronics

The automatic door lock system malfunctioned due to an electrical surge. Currently, the door is closed but the screen shows the door open. We opened the door by pulling the motor handle and putting the motor in neutral, but this time the door does not close.

We closed the door by keeping the motor handle pulled and pressing the door double-sided downwards, the door is now closed, but it still shows open on the screen and this time I get F000 and F035 coded errors on the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What speaks against contacting the manufacturer and asking them for help? https://www.efaflex.com/service/service-international/

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: How can I fix the error code? How can it be restored to its former working state?